# JQuery Font Size Script Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I'm working on a simple script to increase/decrease font-size using Jquery.  Here's the HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Font Sizer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="increase" href="#">+</a><br/>
    <a id="decrease" href="#">-</a>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
</body>
```

The JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textsize = $('p').css("font-size");
    var textunit = textsize.slice(-2);
    textsize = parseFloat(textsize, 10);
    console.log(textsize);

    $('#increase').click(function(){
        textsize++;
        console.log(textsize);

        ('p').css('font-size', textsize + textunit);
    }); 
});
```

I'm working on jsFiddle, so no script tag for Jquery needed.

Could someone tell me why the font size doesn't increase when I click the +?

Comment: I still can't figure it out...console says: Uncaught TypeError: Object p has no method 'css'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting the "$" sign before `('p')`, it should be:

```
$('p').css('font-size', textsize + textunit);
```

Comment: and you have extra });  , remove that

Comment: I dont think so Vivek :) @the_archer dont forget to mark the answer.

Comment: @Mohib - thanks for all the advice! :) | @ mu is too short - yes, I know that $ is an alias for jQuery...but I seem to forget that :p